# ipython: start kernel and kernelmanager in application

Tags: python, kernel, ipython

I'd like to use **ipython** within a Python application. Does anyone have *(or can point to)* a minimal example that:

1. Starts a kernel and..
2. Communicates with it, *i.e. sends and receives messages / code fragments*?

There is an example in the source code docs `ipkernel_qt.py`, but this only shows how to start a kernel from within a script and how to modify the name space and does not show how to send code. I think I need to use a **KernelManager**, but is there a way to connect the kernel manager to a kernel without a configuration file?

Comment: Check my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9796491), maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this a while back and things have changed since, but it isn't difficult to do. There's an [example](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython) in the docs for embedding IPython.

Comment: (this answer is link-only though.)